# Compilation error when adding multiple listeners to Spring batch Step

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-batch

Adding multiple listeners to Step causes compilation error.

```
    private Step myStep(DataSource dataSource) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
            .<Record, Record>chunk(100)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant()
            .listener(stepListener)
            .listener(skipListener)
            .build();
}
```

> [ERROR]   cannot find symbol [ERROR]   symbol:   method build()
>   [ERROR]   location: class
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilderHelper

If I removed one of the listeners, the code compiles. How do I add both step listener and skip listener to a fault tolerant step in Spring Batch?

Using Spring Boot 2.1.8-RELEASE and Spring Batch starter.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is the following, not ideal, but it works.

```
SimpleStepBuilder<Record, Record> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep")
            .<Record, Record>chunk(100)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .faultTolerant();
    builder.listener(skipListener);
    builder.listener(stepListener);
    return builder.build();
```